# Is there an extension for which can be used to store user information into a ldap directory in typo3?

Tags: ldap, typo3

I have installed an LDAP server and finished with its setup. What I would like to know is if an extension exists that will allow me to store users via form submission into a LDAP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here: http://xavier.perseguers.ch/en/tutorials/typo3/articles/ldap-backend-for-extbase.html

Comment: Not exactly the answer but given the domain, it's close enough. :)